# Select single item from each group in multiple groups

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list (specifically IEnumerable) of items of a specific class:

```
internal class MyItem
{
    public MyItem(DateTime timestamp, string code)
    {
        Timestamp= timestamp;
        Code = code;
    }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }

    public string Code { get; private set; }
}
```

Within this list, there will be multiple items with the same code. Each will have a timestamp, which may or may not be unique.

I'm attempting to retrieve a dictionary of MyItem's (`Dictionary<string, MyItem>`) where the key is the code associated with the item.

```
public Dictionary<string, MyItem> GetLatestCodes(IEnumerable<MyItem> items, DateTime latestAllowableTimestamp)
```

Given this signature, how would I retrieve the `MyItem` with a timestamp closest to, but not after `latestAllowableTimestamp` for each code?

For example, given the following for input:

```
IEnumerable<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>{
    new MyItem(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2014"), "1"),
    new MyItem(DateTime.Parse("1/2/2014"), "2"),
    new MyItem(DateTime.Parse("1/3/2014"), "1"),
    new MyItem(DateTime.Parse("1/4/2014"), "1"),
    new MyItem(DateTime.Parse("1/4/2014"), "2")};
```

If the `latestAllowableTimestamp` is 1/3/2014, the result would contain only the following items:

```
Timestamp | Code
----------------
1/3/2014  | 1
1/2/2014  | 2
```

I can manage to filter the list down to only those timestamps prior to `latestAllowableTimestamp`, but I don't know linq well enough to pick the most recent for each code and insert it into a dictionary.

```
var output = items.Where(t => (t.Timestamp <= latestAllowableTimestamp)).GroupBy(t => t.Code);
```

At this point, I've ended up with two groups, but don't know how to select a single item across each group.

Comment: Something like `Where(t=>t.timestamp <=latestAllowableTimestamp ).MaxBy(t=>t.timestamp)` (assuming you have MoreLinq, otherwise implement MaxBy yourself).

Comment: Just post a code to create sample dictionary (so that people can copy&paste) and expected output. That way you can get a complete answer in a few munutes.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Yes, and I imagine that I should have added a bit more information to the original post. I've edited it, but it looks like the question is doomed to be downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: @UnSined If you actually want people to get a notification, make sure you @ them, like I've done for you. Note that you can only do that for one person per comment. The owner of the post (in this case, you) is always notified regardless of @.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the your part you should have posted in your question (as LB pointed out)

```
var list = new List<MyItem>()
{
    new MyItem(){ code = "1" , timestamp = new DateTime(2014,1,1)},
    new MyItem(){ code = "2" , timestamp = new DateTime(2014,1,2)},
    new MyItem(){ code = "1" , timestamp = new DateTime(2014,1,3)},
    new MyItem(){ code = "1" , timestamp = new DateTime(2014,1,4)},
    new MyItem(){ code = "2" , timestamp = new DateTime(2014,1,4)}  
};

DateTime latestAllowableTimestamp = new DateTime(2014, 1, 3);
```

This is my answer

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.code)
             .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.timestamp)
                           .FirstOrDefault(z => z.timestamp <= latestAllowableTimestamp))
             .ToList();
```

Comment: He asked for a dictionary. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Don't edit my answer please. If you have another one post it, (BTW: There is no meaning in *ToDictionary* here)

Comment: This has put me much closer to what I was looking for. In my case, a dictionary is important. When switching .ToList() to .ToDictionary(c=>c.Code), and using the latestAllowableTimestamp of 1/1/2014, a NullReferenceException is thrown, I imagine because there is no allowable value for code 2. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you filter away invalid elements before grouping you won't have the issue.

Comment: @UnSined What will be the key and the value for the dictionary you expect?

Comment: @EZI: suit yourself. Note however that your answer doesn't answer the question asked (since it returns a list instead of a dictionary).  (BTW, there most certainly is "meaning" to `ToDictonary()` here...it works just fine as I edited it)

Comment: @PrestonGuillot This seems to work for me. Is there anything that you can see that would cause an issue with it?             `var result = items.Where(z => z.Timestamp <= latestAllowableTimestamp)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Code).Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(d => d.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()).ToDictionary(c => c.Code);`

Comment: @EZI MyItem.Code will be the key, and MyItem will be the value.

Comment: @UnSined then you can use `.ToDictionary(x => x.code, x => x);`

Comment: You can just use `First`, you no longer need a `FirstOrDefault`. Rather than either I'd probably include the MoreLinq package and use `MaxBy` as was pointed out in the comments on the question intself.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the actual method you are trying to write. It even returns a dictionary and everything:

```
static Dictionary<string, MyItem> GetLatestCodes(
    IEnumerable<MyItem> items, DateTime latestAllowableTimestamp)
{
    return items
        .Where(item => item.TimeStamp <= latestAllowableTimestamp)
        .GroupBy(item => item.Code)
        .Select(group => group
            .OrderByDescending(item => item.TimeStamp)
            .First())
        .ToDictionary(item => item.Code);
}
```

See [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To create your Dictionary, could construct your query like so:

```
var newDict = items.Where(a => a.Timestamp <= latestAllowableTimestamp)
               .GroupBy(b => b.Timestamp)
               .ToDictionary(c => c.First().Timestamp, c => c.First());
```

This should create a Dictionary from your data, with no duplicate days. Note that without the `GroupBy` query, you'll raise an exception, because `ToDictionary` doesn't filter out keys it's already seen.

And then if you wanted to get only one MyItem for any given code number, you could use this query:

```
newDict.Select(a => a.Value)
       .OrderByDescending(b => b.Timestamp)
       .GroupBy(c => c.Code)
       .Select(d => d.First());
```

The `FirstOrDefault` query will return only one element from each group. This will give you the MyItem closest to the latest date for any given code.